# Fetching a github repo in react gives a "Module "stream" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, github-api, vite

I am currently stuck with a problem trying to fetch github repo data using the octokit npm package.
I use vite to run a dev server and when I try to make a request, the error that i get is:

```
Uncaught Error: Module "stream" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code.
```

My React .tsx file looks like this:

```
import { Octokit, App } from 'octokit'
import React from 'react'

const key = import.meta.env.GITHUB_KEY
const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: key
  })
await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}', {
    owner: 'OWNER',
    repo: 'REPO'
  })
  
export default function Repos() {

  return (
    <>

    </>
  )
}
```

I have redacted the information for privacy purposes.
If anyone knows how to resolve this issue with vite, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [`octokit/octokit.js` issue 2126](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js/issues/2126)

> I worked around this problem by aliasing node-fetch to isomorphic-fetch. No idea if it works for all usages within octokit, but works fine for my project.
>
> You'll need to install the `isomorphic-fetch` dependency before making this config change.
>
> ```js
> // svelte.config.js
>
> const config = {   // ...   kit: {
>     // ...
>     vite: {
>       resolve: {
>        alias: {
>          'node-fetch': 'isomorphic-fetch',
>        },
>      },
>    },
>  },
> };
>
> export default config;
> ```

Note: there are still questions about the support/development of octokit: [issue 620](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js/discussions/620#discussioncomment-1472174).